# Web based visual query builder

Tags: asp.net, query-builder

I am after a visual query builder along the lines of http://ajax.easyquerydemo.com/. I am using ASP.NET but MVC so would rather something that is not WebForms based like the one in the link. If anyone knows of similar tools that are largely platform agnostic please let me know.

Comment: We ended up just building our own, could find none that worked they way we wanted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was looking for the same sort of thing, came across this http://devtools.korzh.com/query-builder-component/ which looks very interesting to me...

Answer (score 2):

[Easy Query Builder](http://easyquerybuilder.com/) supports MVC, they have a pretty [slick MVC Demo](http://demo.easyquerybuilder.com/asp-net-mvc/), and a non-expiring trial.

Comment: This is the same one as @doza gave above :)

Answer (score 2):

Activer query can do all the thing you want:

http://www.activequerybuilder.com/product.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [www.ajaxquerybuilder.com](http://www.ajaxquerybuilder.com)

Answer (score 1):

Even i search for it today and created a list:

1) Query builder
http://aspquerybuilder.net/?_ga=2.150945718.1618902383.1522751533-1013206784.1522751533
price : https://www.activequerybuilder.com/purchase.html

2)  Active query builder
Demo : https://webapi.activequerybuilder.com/Demo
Free to use.

3)  Custom code
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1060170/User-Responsive-Web-Query-Builder-using-ASP-NET

4)  DataSparc: Paid service
Demo : https://www.datasparc.com/dbhawk-online-demo/

5)  Jquery query builder: Free to use.
Demo: http://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html
GitHub: https://github.com/mistic100/jQuery-QueryBuilder

6)  DevExpress.com
Demo : https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/DataBinding/QueryBuilder.aspx
Documentation: https://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/DataBinding/QueryBuilderControl.aspx

Comment: The 5th "jQuery-QueryBuilder" is just what I need.